# Does JAX-RS needs a war module?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jax-rs, ear

Does JAX-RS needs an web-module `WAR` or am i doing something wrong?

Every tutorial states to config the rest-service in `web.xml`. 
But in ejb-module there is no `web.xml`. Must I create a `WAR` just for the rest service?

In my ejb module I want to expose a EJB as a rest service but cannot get it to work. 
Calling "localhost:8080/EjbModule/rest/test/method" leads to 404

**Project structure**

```
- ear
    - EjbModule.jar
```

**Code**

*Exposing a Bean as a JAX-WS web service and testing it in browser is no problem.*

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class RestApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()
    {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>(1);
        classes.add(TestService.class);
        return classes;
    }
}


@Stateless
@Path("/test")
public class TestService
{
    @Path("/method")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String test()
    {
        return new Date().toString();
    }
}
```

Environment: Glassfish 4.0

**Edit:**

Creating a separate `WAR` the rest service works as expected.

Comment: Definitely, you can explose an EJB as a REST service. I suspect your URL misses something between your server+port and the RESTful service path.

Comment: I created a separate `WAR` project bundled in the ear and the rest service works as expected. But this is not really an elegant solution having an basically empty project just defining the rest interfaces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [JAX-RS Specification 2.0](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf) p. 8:

> #### 2.3.2 Servlet
>
> A JAX-RS application is packaged as a Web application in a .war ﬁle. The application classes are packaged in WEB-INF/classes or
> WEB-INF/lib and required libraries are packaged in WEB-INF/lib. See
> the Servlet speciﬁcation for full details on packaging of web
> applications.

This is the standard way if you want to deploy your JAX-RS application in a web-container. However the specification points also out that applications can run in different containers like ejb-containers or even an Java SE environment. But for other containers there is nothing specified:

> An implementation MAY provide facilities to host a JAX-RS application in other types of container, such facilities are outside the scope of this speciﬁcation.

Comment: Thank you, it just seems so cumbersome just to create a new `war ` project just for the rest functionality. But will stick with it till now.

Comment: Don't know your project and so can't say which structure makes sense but [do you really need an ear-file?](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/is_java_ee_6_war)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post but i solved the problem with a trick.

I have a lot of EAR that include different EJB.

For example, EAR_A include EJB_1 and EJB_2 while EAR_B include EJB_1 and EJB_3.

The WAR is shared across all the EARs. I would to remove it but i can't.
I use the WAR only for `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`.

In this class, I read a database table with "rest-resource" and i add the classes.
Each ear has its content loaded on  database the first time.

For example, here is the method for Exception Mapper and Filters

```
private void addFilterAndExceptionMappersClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources){
  javax.naming.InitialContext ctx;
  try {
      ctx = new InitialContext();
      RestResourceFacadeRemote rrfr = (RestResourceFacadeRemote) ctx.lookup(this.wsresource);
      if(rrfr == null){
          LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "{0} is null", "RestResourceFacadeRemote");
      }
      String classe = "no class";
      if (rrfr.getEntityClass()!= null) {
        classe = rrfr.getEntityClass().getClasse();
      }

      List<RestResource> lr = rrfr.getListaPerTipo(RestResourceType.Filter);
      for(RestResource r : lr){
        try{
            Class<?> c = Class.forName(r.getRisorsa());
            resources.add(c);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
          LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Class not found for filter {0}",r.getRisorsa());
        }
      }
      lr = rrfr.getListaPerTipo(RestResourceType.ExceptionMapper);
      for(RestResource r : lr){
        try{
           Class<?> c = Class.forName(r.getRisorsa());
           resources.add(c);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
          LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Classe per exception mapper {0} non trovata!",r.getRisorsa());
        }
      }
  } catch (NamingException ex) {
      LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Cannot read context", ex);
  } catch (EJBException ex){
      LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "EJB exception: ", ex);
  }

}
```

Maybe you can do the same without a database, using a file. You need only a list of classname to add in the `resources.add(c)`.

I only include the same WAR in each EAR's application.xml.