# rest project building ear not war

Tags: rest, war, ear

I have a RESTful project that I've built with Maven3 as an EAR. I have created a module project (EAR, EJB),but not sure if that will deploy in JBOSS EAp

Is it possible to build Java RESTful project as EAR to make it work on JBoss EAP instead of WAR file?

Comment: But isn't that what you've just done?! Because your first statement answers your own question. It seems that your question may be other... am I right?

Comment: @aribeiro I actually meant yes build possible but if i can successfully  deploy on JBOSS EAP bcus war files is asking web.xml for proper build ,so im not sure if EAR will deploy or it is proper way to deploy on EAP 6? ty

Comment: I think [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196338/does-jax-rs-needs-a-war-module) answers to your question.