# Want to deploy EJB with rest api in ear, is this possible?

Tags: rest, deployment, ejb-3.0, ear

Want to expose restful api in EJB project and deploy that api in EAR file, is any way for doing this if yes the please assist me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible. Could you please extend your question with the information about the application server you are using and include examples of projects structure and deployment descriptors used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does JAX-RS needs a war module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196338/does-jax-rs-needs-a-war-module)