# RESTEasy won't bootstrap/initialize

Tags: java, rest, wildfly, resteasy

I'm attempting to use WildFly's implementation of JAX-RS - RESTEasy to create some Java based Restful webservices, and having a little trouble simply getting it to initiate once deployed.

Note that I'm adding the RESTEasy annotations to a set of classes in an already working project that is deployed as an .ear file, that should be OK right? To be clear the package structure looks something like:

```
com.something.app
com.something.app.resteasyannotatedclasses
```

Now I am using no web.xml or any xml conf for that matter and only annotations as documented [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/resteasy/resteasy-tutorial)

I simply have two classes, the RESTEasy Activator:

```
@ApplicationPath("/coordinates")
public class RestEasyActivator extends Application {
    RestEasyActivator () {
        Logger.getAnonymousLogger().warning("RestEasyActivator Initialised Rest Easy.");
    }
}
```

And the actual service:

```
@Path("get")
public class CoordinatesServiceWrapper {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(CoordinatesServiceWrapper.class.getName());

    @GET
    @Path("getByName")
    public String findCoordinates(){
        LOG.info("Called coordinates service!");
        return "Hi";
    }
}
```

When the ear is deployed to WildFly I see the log:

> WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 4) WELD-000167: Class org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsynchronousDispatcher is annotated with @RequestScoped but it does not declare an appropriate constructor therefore is not registered as a bean!
>
> WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 1) WELD-000167: Class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.DocumentProvider is annotated with @ApplicationScoped but it does not declare an appropriate constructor therefore is not registered as a bean!
>
> INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 391) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/CoordinateSearch' for server 'default-server'
>
> INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "CoordinateSearch.ear" (runtime-name : "CoordinateSearch.ear")

Im guessing the warnings relating to RESTEasy are fine to ignore, and the info messages show that the .ear has successfully deployed.

To invoke the webservice I've tried the URLS:

> Server:port/CoordinateSearch/coordinates/get/getByName/ and
> Server:port/coordinates/get/getByName/

Neither of which generate any log entries.

What am I missing...
Have I missed some conf? - it seems very minimal. Based on the RESTEasy documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.1.1.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#resteasy_modules_in_wildfly) WildFly comes with RESTEasy imported and it will bootstrap based on any classes containing annotations ...So I can't see the issue.

Comment: You say that there's no log entry, but do you have a response from the server ?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel No response, just a 404. There is a logger in the RESTEasy Activator constructor, so without a log entry I'm guessing it hasn't been initialized at all.

Answer (score 0):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24217275/7736617), JAX-RS should normally be packaged in a `.war` file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the solution was to set the scope of resteasy dependencies to provided rather than compile.